# How to allow user that after order placed before shipping user can update the product quantity in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Scenario

1. User loges and selected 3 products e.g. A - 2 Quantity , B - 1 Quantity , C - 4 Quantity
2. After selecting user placed order.
3. Now user thinks that wrong quantity of product selected and s/he wants to update quantity like A - 4, B - 2, C - 1

How we can achieve this scenario using code, API or App in Shopify

Answer (score 0):

order placed is order placed.

Anything happened after, eg. price, quantity, cannot modify.

You can cancel the order, create a new order manually with different quantity within Shopify Admin.

Comment: Thank you for the update, actually we need feature that allow customer to update their order, so is there any plugin who provide this type of support

Comment: none that I know of. All major ecommerce platform that I have used never have this features since it brings many problems in transaction.